# Draw something on an image with python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, draw

I am trying to do my assignment which ask me to draw a line like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDIcI.png)

the center point perpendicular to diagonal and the code is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.open(image_path)

image_width, image_height = image.size

k1 = image_height / image_width
b1 = 0
k2 = -k1
b2 = image_height

x1 = (max_center[1] - b1) / k1
x2 = (max_center[1] - b2) / k2
y1 = k1 * x1 + b1
y2 = k2 * x2 + b2

plt.plot([0, image_width], [b1, k1 * image_width + b1], 'r')
plt.plot([0, image_width], [b2, k2 * image_width + b2], 'r')

plt.plot([max_center[0] * image_width, x1], [max_center[1] * image_height, y1], 'r')
plt.plot([max_center[0] * image_width, x2], [max_center[1] * image_height, y2], 'r')

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

and when I run the code it gives me the picture like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DJ9R.png)

how should I achieve it

Comment: and eventually I should caculate the distance between the center and the vertical point, how should I do this :(

Comment: What is `max_center`, it is not defined in your code. Also what do you mean by "vertical point"?

Comment: max center is defined in another part of code, and vertical point, to my understanding, maybe means foot of perpendicular?  It is the point that a line vertical to another

Comment: and max_center is the center point I mentioned above

Comment: is `max_center` an arbitrary point or what is it the center of?

Comment: In fact the max_center is for a bounding box, I have many bounding box in an image, and the bounding box has the biggest area, the center is for the biggest, so it is not arbitrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lines

```
plt.plot([max_center[0] * image_width, x1], [max_center[1] * image_height, y1], 'r')
plt.plot([max_center[0] * image_width, x2], [max_center[1] * image_height, y2], 'r')
```

don't make any sense to me. You are multiplying coordinates of a point with the image dimensions.

I'll try to guide you through the necessary caculations.
For this example I used an arbitrary point at 50, 150, but it will work for any other point as well.

For calculating the slope `k_perp` of a line perpendicular to one with slope `k` I used:
`k_perp * k = -1`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.open(image_path)

image_width, image_height = image.size


k1 = image_height / image_width
b1 = 0
k2 = -k1
b2 = image_height

plt.plot([0, image_width], [b1, k1 * image_width + b1], 'r')
plt.plot([0, image_width], [b2, k2 * image_width + b2], 'r')

# definition of point
point_x = 50
point_y = 150
plt.plot(point_x, point_y, 'r.', label='Point')

# line perpendicular to diagonal 1 and containing point
k_perp = -1/k1
b_perp = point_y - point_x * k_perp

# calculating foot point for diagonal 1
x = (b_perp - b1) / (k1 - k_perp)
y = k1 * x + b1

plt.plot([point_x, x],[point_y, y], 'g', label='Perpendicular line 1')


# line perpendicular to diagonal 2 and containing point
k_perp = -1/k2
b_perp = point_y - point_x * k_perp

# calculating foot point for diagonal 2
x = (b_perp - b2) / (k2 - k_perp)
y = k2 * x + b2

plt.plot([point_x, x],[point_y, y], 'g', label='Perpendicular line 2')


plt.imshow(image)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

From this, calculating the distance between the point to the diagonals should be straight forward.